# Setting the value of a variable after running the first test in xUnit

Tags: xunit, xunit.net

I have several tests in a class. However, one of those tests sends a POST request to an API and receives an ID. I need to use that ID for the rest of the tests.

I guess it would need to satisfy two things:

1. Make sure that the test that gets the ID is always executed first.
2. Set the value of the variable after the first test and use it for the remaining tests.

Comment: Fetch the Id in the constructor or a Fixture? [See here](https://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html)

Comment: Class Fixture makes sense - you get a thing to share, and it can hold/initialize that state (even asynchronously if necessary)